# Why did Hera have so many sacred things?

Tags: greek, symbolism, hera

[Theoi](http://www.theoi.com/Summary/Hera.html) has quite the list.

**SYMBOLS**

- Crown, Lotus-staff, Cuckoo

**ATTRIBUTES**

- Lotus-staff; Crown; Cuckoo; Peacock; Pomegranate

**<strike>CHARIOTS</strike>** Who cares?

**SACRED PLANTS**

- Pomegranate, Lotus/Waterlily, Willow

**SACRED ANIMALS**

- Heifer, Lion

**SACRED BIRDS**

- Cuckoo, Peacock, Wide Winged Hawk, and Crane

**SACRED PLANET**

- Venus

She even stole another goddess' Planet.

Is there a tangible reason why she has so many symbols and sacred stuff?

Comment: The problem with this list is context. All of the gods, and especially the major ones, had plenty that were sacred to them. The ancient Greeks lived in a very sacred world, and the distinction between the sacred and the secular was non-existent.

Comment: Just look at Dionysus for comparison: http://www.theoi.com/Summary/Dionysos.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't look at a God as an equivalent of a person with a distinct and very limited identity. The gods we more fluid in how they were represented and worshipped and during the time in which they were worshipped. When simply enumerating that Hera's sacred birds are a Cuckoo, Peacock, etc., you lose that people living in one community may have had a lot of Peacocks but had never seen a Cuckoo before, so they naturally revered the Peacock instead.

> Priest: And Hera's sacred bird is the Cuckoo
>
> Worshiper: Ohh. What's a "Cuckoo"?
>
> Priest: Uhm, [*looks around frantically*] ... that bird over there!
>
> Worshiper: ...Looks kind of like a Peacock to me.
>
> Priest: Well, it would. That is why I am a priest. Now kneel before the goddess and pray or I will give you such a pinch!!